# Read a pdf from WCF Data Service

Tags: wcf-data-services, silverlight-5.0

I added a WCF Data Service like:

```
[WebGet]
public byte[] GetPdf(int id)
{
...
return result;
}
```

and when I call from browser

```
http://localhost:50300/data/MyService/GetPdf?id=114
```

I get a response like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:GetPdf m:type="Edm.Binary"
 xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">JVBERi0xLjQNCiXi48/TDQolDQold1BERjMgYnkgV1
 ...</d:GetPdf>
```

Then I try to read the bytes in a silverlight client with

```
 private void ReadPdf()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:50300/data/MyService/GetPdf?id=114");
        var myQuery = client.BeginExecute(uri, MyCallback, null, "GET", null);
    }
```

and in MyCallback

```
  public void MyCallback(IAsyncResult result)
  {
     ???
  }
```

in result I get a System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult but I don't know how read it.

Answer (score 0):

See this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd756367(v=vs.100).aspx

Essentially you want something like this:

```
// Get the original query from the result.
DataServiceQuery<Customer> query = result as DataServiceQuery<Customer>;

byte[] resultBytes = query.EndExecute(result))
// Convert the bytes to your PDF or whatever
```

How you do the conversion back is up to you; that depends on your you serialized the bytes of course.